# change the seaborn pairplot diagonal color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, visualization

When using the `sns.pairplot` I have this:

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.pairplot(iris, 
                 markers="+",
                 kind='reg',
                 diag_kind="kde",
                 plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'#aec6cf'}, 
                           'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.5, 
                                           'color': '#82ad32'}},
                 corner=True)
```

Pairplot without kde colors:

[image]

But I need to change the diagonal color of the plot, but when I try `diag_kws`, I have the following error:

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.pairplot(iris, 
                 markers="+",
                 kind='reg',
                 diag_kind="kde",
                 plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'#aec6cf'}, 
                           'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.5, 
                                           'color': '#82ad32'}, 
                           'diag_kws': {'color': '#82ad32'}},
                 corner=True)

TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'diag_kws'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the `diag_kws` as a parameter of `pairplot` itself, not as a key of the `plot_kws` parameter, like this:

```
g = sns.pairplot(iris,
                 markers="+",
                 kind='reg',
                 diag_kind="kde",
                 plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'#aec6cf'},
                           'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.5,
                                           'color': '#82ad32'}},
                 corner=True,
                 diag_kws= {'color': '#82ad32'})
```

[image]